# Pass Query String to rDirectory

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to pass a query string to Namescape's [rDirectory](http://www.namescape.com/Products/rDirectory/Default.aspx)? I'd like to build a web-app that can do a search and display the results in rDirectory, rather than first launching rDirectory and doing said search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around and peeking at some rDirectory code, it looks like the query string would look something like this: Results.aspx?CatalogKey=2&FilterExp=x&WhereTxt=x&SortFields=cn. Unfortunately, both "FilterExp" and "WhereTxt" values are passed as encrypted text.

Looks like some time, effort, and perhaps some reverse engineering of the rDirectory web app would be required to get any further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Namescape's rDirectory, the query string would look similar to this:

http://[servername]/?runapp=b05810fe-be2c-4a12-b3a9-858bbb71eff1&AutoSearch=true&cn=alice%20cooper&telephoneNumber=*867*

the runapp guid is captured from the rDirectory application page in the Designer menu.  If you have more questions about this, please contact support@namescape.com